# All topologies on a finite metric space are homeomorphic to the product topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X^n=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and let $d$ be a metric on $X^n$.  Is is true that $(X,d)$ is homeomorphic to $\coprod_{i=1}^n \{x_i\}$ equipped with the product topology?  (Where here each $\{x_i\}$ is equipped with the trivial/finest topology on ${x_i}?)

Comment: Given that the product of singletons is a singleton again, I don't see how this can be true. Did you think of the disjoint union topology instead?

Comment: With the disjoint union, the answer is yes: a finite subset of a Haussdorf space is always *discrete*.

Comment: Yes sorry, that was silly of me.  That is what I meant.  If you post that as an answer with a reference I would happily accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A finite metric space is discrete. Indeed, let $(X,d)$ be a finite metric space. Define

$$D=\inf\{d(x, y)\}_{x\neq y}$$

and note that since $X$ is finite then the set $\{d(x,y)\}_{x\neq y}$ is a finite set of positive numbers and so $D>0$. With this you can easily check that $B(x, D)=\{x\}$ for any $x\in X$. Here on the left side we have "the open ball centered at $x$ of radius $D$". In particular $\{x\}$ is open and hence $X$ is discrete.

And so all finite metric spaces are discrete. Therefore homeomorphic to the *disjoint union* of their own points, not to product.